# how to use as source the first element of the main source?

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have a dataGrid that binding the itemSource. This itemSource has a collection of elements (related entities for a weak relationship)that for design has only one element.

I would like to show in the dataGrid the properties of this related entities, so I I am trying this binding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="IDRelatedEntity" Binding="{Binding RelatedEntities.ElementAt(0).IRelatedEntity, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

But this show nothing.

I know that I could use a converter for this, but I would like to avoid the use of a converter for this, I guess that it would be a simple way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Use this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="IDRelatedEntity" Binding="{Binding RelatedEntities[0].IRelatedEntity, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: this was another way that I tried, but neither it does not work.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Run your program and look in the `Output` window. See if you have any binding errors.

Comment: Other properties of the main entity is binding corectly, but the navigation property RelatedEntities is like I can't access to its properties.